# Convert int to System.Drawing.Brushes.SomeColor?

Tags: c#, colors, numbers, drawing, brushes

I imagine those `System.Drawing.Brushes.SomeColor` can eventually break down to some numbers, or vectors perhaps, such as 0 is black and 255 is white in a 8-bit gray scale representation.

So I am wondering is there any chance an integer can be converted to `System.Drawing.Brushes.SomeColor`? Or perhaps an integer array like (a,a,a), where `int a = someNumber;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Color.ToArgb and Color.FromArgb to convert color values to integers:

```
int blueInt = System.Drawing.Color.Blue.ToArgb();
var colorBlue = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(blueInt);
```

You can create a solid brush from a color like so:

```
SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(blueColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant convert an integer directly, but you can create one from an RGB set:

`Color.FromArgb` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx))

Will take an set of ints as you expect, one for red, one for green, and one for blue. A different overload of that method allows you to specify the alpha value.

You then create a brush from the color:

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(myColor);
```

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.solidbrush(v=vs.110).aspx))